# How I am able to use Behat 3.1 with Selenium 3.6 and Mink?

Tags: php, testing, behat, mink, selenium-server

I've been trying unsuccessfully to creat some tests with Behat 3.1, Selenium 3.6 and Mink... I have not any idea how I am able to solve this problem: If I fire the command `php bin/behat` my Firefox starts but my site doesn't load. I just get an error after some minutes:

> Scenario: visit login page
>       Given I am on '/login'
>         Could not open connection: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       
>   Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T16:15:40.131Z'
>   
>   System info: host: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', ip: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13', java.version: '1.8.0_72'
>   
>   Driver info: driver.version: unknown (Behat\Mink\Exception\DriverException)
>   When I press 'Startseite'
>   Then I should see 'einloggen'

## My behat.yml

```
# behat.yml
default:
  autoload: %paths.base%/features/bootstrap
  extensions:
    Behat\Symfony2Extension: ~
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      base_url: http://myWebsite
      default_session: selenium2
      selenium2:
        browser: firefox
        wd_host: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
        capabilities: { "platform": 'MAC', "browser": 'firefox', "version": '56' }
```

## My FeatureContext.php

```
use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\PyStringNode;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\TableNode;

class FeatureContext extends MinkContext implements Context
{

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * @Given I am on :arg1
     */
    public function iAmOn($arg1)
    {
        $this->visit($arg1);
    }

    /**
     * @When I press :arg1
     */
    public function iPress($arg1)
    {
        $this->getSession()
            ->getPage()
            ->findButton($arg1)
            ->press();
    }

    /**
     * @Then I should see :arg1
     */
    public function iShouldSee($arg1)
    {
        $this->assertPageContainsText($arg1);
    }
}
```

## My login.feature

```
Feature: login page
    In order to see login contens
    As a user
    I am able to visit login page

    @javascript @login
    Scenario: visit login page
        Given I am on '/login'
        When  I press 'Startseite'
        Then  I should see 'einloggen'
```

## My GuiContext

```
    use Behat\Behat\Context\BehatContext;
    use Behat\Gherkin\Node\PyStringNode;

    use Behat\Mink\Mink,
        Behat\Mink\Session,
        Behat\Mink\Driver\Selenium2Driver,
        Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;

    use Nearsoft\SeleniumClient as SeleniumClient;

    require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';
    require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework/Assert/Functions.php';

    class GuiContext extends MinkContext
    {

        public function __construct(array $parameters)
        {
            $mink = new Mink(array(
                'selenium2' => new Session(new Selenium2Driver($parameters['wd_capabilities']['browser'], $parameters['wd_capabilities'], $parameters['wd_host'])),
            ));
            $this->gui = $mink->getSession('selenium2');
        }

        /**
         * @When /^wait (\d+) seconds?$/
         */
        public function waitSeconds($seconds)
        {
            $this->getSession()->wait(1000*$seconds);
        }
    }
```

I have read lot of forums and honestly I am just confused now...

I am thankful to any kind of help!

best regards 
Emmanuel

#### Update 1:

I tried to start my behat with `php bin/behat` 
after the command `php bin/behat -vvv`I got this error msg:

```
Emmanuel@Emmanuel-macOS:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/symfony$ php bin/behat -vvv
Feature: login page
    In order to see login contents
    As a user
    I am able to visit login page

  @javascript @login
  Scenario: dashboard         # features/login.feature:7
    Given I am on '/'         # FeatureContext::iAmOn()
      WebDriver\Exception\SessionNotCreated: Unable to create a new session because of no configuration.
      Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T16:15:40.131Z'
      System info: host: 'Emmanuel-macOS.local', ip: '192.168.178.31', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13', java.version: '1.8.0_72'
      Driver info: driver.version: unknown in vendor/instaclick/php-webdriver/lib/WebDriver/Exception.php:155
      Stack trace:
      #0 vendor/instaclick/php-webdriver/lib/WebDriver/AbstractWebDriver.php(157): WebDriver\Exception::factory(33, 'Unable to creat...')
      #1 vendor/instaclick/php-webdriver/lib/WebDriver/WebDriver.php(70): WebDriver\AbstractWebDriver->curl('POST', '/session', Array, Array)
      #2 vendor/behat/mink-selenium2-driver/src/Selenium2Driver.php(307): WebDriver\WebDriver->session(Array, Array)
      #3 vendor/behat/mink/src/Session.php(70): Behat\Mink\Driver\Selenium2Driver->start()
      #4 vendor/behat/mink/src/Session.php(145): Behat\Mink\Session->start()
      #5 vendor/behat/mink-extension/src/Behat/MinkExtension/Context/RawMinkContext.php(131): Behat\Mink\Session->visit('http://l3ams3/')
      #6 vendor/behat/mink-extension/src/Behat/MinkExtension/Context/MinkContext.php(49): Behat\MinkExtension\Context\RawMinkContext->visitPath('/')
      #7 features/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php(21): Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext->visit('/')
      #8 [internal function]: FeatureContext->iAmOn('/')
      #9 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Call/Handler/RuntimeCallHandler.php(104): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
      #10 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Call/Handler/RuntimeCallHandler.php(60): Behat\Testwork\Call\Handler\RuntimeCallHandler->executeCall(Object(Behat\Behat\Definition\Call\DefinitionCall))
      #11 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Call/CallCenter.php(129): Behat\Testwork\Call\Handler\RuntimeCallHandler->handleCall(Object(Behat\Behat\Definition\Call\DefinitionCall))
      #12 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Call/CallCenter.php(82): Behat\Testwork\Call\CallCenter->handleCall(Object(Behat\Behat\Definition\Call\DefinitionCall))
      #13 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Tester/Runtime/RuntimeStepTester.php(125): Behat\Testwork\Call\CallCenter->makeCall(Object(Behat\Behat\Definition\Call\DefinitionCall))
      #14 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Tester/Runtime/RuntimeStepTester.php(73): Behat\Behat\Tester\Runtime\RuntimeStepTester->testDefinition(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\InitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\FeatureNode), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\StepNode), Object(Behat\Behat\Definition\SearchResult), false)
      #15 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Hook/Tester/HookableStepTester.php(74): Behat\Behat\Tester\Runtime\RuntimeStepTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\InitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\FeatureNode), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\StepNode), false)
      #16 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/EventDispatcher/Tester/EventDispatchingStepTester.php(73): Behat\Behat\Hook\Tester\HookableStepTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\InitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\FeatureNode), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\StepNode), false)
      #17 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Tester/StepContainerTester.php(59): Behat\Behat\EventDispatcher\Tester\EventDispatchingStepTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\InitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\FeatureNode), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\StepNode), false)
      #18 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Tester/Runtime/RuntimeScenarioTester.php(76): Behat\Behat\Tester\StepContainerTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\InitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\FeatureNode), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\ScenarioNode), false)
      #19 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Hook/Tester/HookableScenarioTester.php(74): Behat\Behat\Tester\Runtime\RuntimeScenarioTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\InitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\FeatureNode), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\ScenarioNode), false)
      #20 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/EventDispatcher/Tester/EventDispatchingScenarioTester.php(103): Behat\Behat\Hook\Tester\HookableScenarioTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\InitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\FeatureNode), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\ScenarioNode), false)
      #21 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Tester/Runtime/RuntimeFeatureTester.php(83): Behat\Behat\EventDispatcher\Tester\EventDispatchingScenarioTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\InitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\FeatureNode), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\ScenarioNode), false)
      #22 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Hook/Tester/HookableFeatureTester.php(72): Behat\Behat\Tester\Runtime\RuntimeFeatureTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\UninitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\FeatureNode), false)
      #23 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/EventDispatcher/Tester/EventDispatchingFeatureTester.php(71): Behat\Behat\Hook\Tester\HookableFeatureTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\UninitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\FeatureNode), false)
      #24 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Tester/Runtime/RuntimeSuiteTester.php(63): Behat\Behat\EventDispatcher\Tester\EventDispatchingFeatureTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\UninitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\FeatureNode), false)
      #25 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Hook/Tester/HookableSuiteTester.php(73): Behat\Testwork\Tester\Runtime\RuntimeSuiteTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\UninitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Testwork\Specification\GroupedSpecificationIterator), false)
      #26 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/EventDispatcher/Tester/EventDispatchingSuiteTester.php(72): Behat\Testwork\Hook\Tester\HookableSuiteTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\UninitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Testwork\Specification\GroupedSpecificationIterator), false)
      #27 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Tester/Runtime/RuntimeExercise.php(71): Behat\Testwork\EventDispatcher\Tester\EventDispatchingSuiteTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\UninitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Testwork\Specification\GroupedSpecificationIterator), false)
      #28 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/EventDispatcher/Tester/EventDispatchingExercise.php(70): Behat\Testwork\Tester\Runtime\RuntimeExercise->test(Array, false)
      #29 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Ordering/OrderedExercise.php(80): Behat\Testwork\EventDispatcher\Tester\EventDispatchingExercise->test(Array, false)
      #30 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Tester/Cli/ExerciseController.php(146): Behat\Testwork\Ordering\OrderedExercise->test(Array, false)
      #31 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Tester/Cli/ExerciseController.php(108): Behat\Testwork\Tester\Cli\ExerciseController->testSpecifications(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Array)
      #32 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Cli/Command.php(63): Behat\Testwork\Tester\Cli\ExerciseController->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      #33 vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php(262): Behat\Testwork\Cli\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      #34 vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(888): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      #35 vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(224): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Behat\Testwork\Cli\Command), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      #36 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Cli/Application.php(121): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      #37 vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(125): Behat\Testwork\Cli\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      #38 vendor/behat/behat/bin/behat(32): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
      #39 {main}

      Next Behat\Mink\Exception\DriverException: Could not open connection: Unable to create a new session because of no configuration.
      Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T16:15:40.131Z'
      System info: host: 'Emmanuel-macOS.local', ip: '192.168.178.31', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13', java.version: '1.8.0_72'
      Driver info: driver.version: unknown in vendor/behat/mink-selenium2-driver/src/Selenium2Driver.php:310
      Stack trace:
      #0 vendor/behat/mink/src/Session.php(70): Behat\Mink\Driver\Selenium2Driver->start()
      #1 vendor/behat/mink/src/Session.php(145): Behat\Mink\Session->start()
      #2 vendor/behat/mink-extension/src/Behat/MinkExtension/Context/RawMinkContext.php(131): Behat\Mink\Session->visit('http://l3ams3/')
      #3 vendor/behat/mink-extension/src/Behat/MinkExtension/Context/MinkContext.php(49): Behat\MinkExtension\Context\RawMinkContext->visitPath('/')
      #4 features/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php(21): Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext->visit('/')
      #5 [internal function]: FeatureContext->iAmOn('/')
      #6 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Call/Handler/RuntimeCallHandler.php(104): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
      #7 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Call/Handler/RuntimeCallHandler.php(60): Behat\Testwork\Call\Handler\RuntimeCallHandler->executeCall(Object(Behat\Behat\Definition\Call\DefinitionCall))
      #8 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Call/CallCenter.php(129): Behat\Testwork\Call\Handler\RuntimeCallHandler->handleCall(Object(Behat\Behat\Definition\Call\DefinitionCall))
      #9 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Call/CallCenter.php(82): Behat\Testwork\Call\CallCenter->handleCall(Object(Behat\Behat\Definition\Call\DefinitionCall))
      #10 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Tester/Runtime/RuntimeStepTester.php(125): Behat\Testwork\Call\CallCenter->makeCall(Object(Behat\Behat\Definition\Call\DefinitionCall))
      #11 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Tester/Runtime/RuntimeStepTester.php(73): Behat\Behat\Tester\Runtime\RuntimeStepTester->testDefinition(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\InitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\FeatureNode), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\StepNode), Object(Behat\Behat\Definition\SearchResult), false)
      #12 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Hook/Tester/HookableStepTester.php(74): Behat\Behat\Tester\Runtime\RuntimeStepTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\InitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\FeatureNode), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\StepNode), false)
      #13 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/EventDispatcher/Tester/EventDispatchingStepTester.php(73): Behat\Behat\Hook\Tester\HookableStepTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\InitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\FeatureNode), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\StepNode), false)
      #14 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Tester/StepContainerTester.php(59): Behat\Behat\EventDispatcher\Tester\EventDispatchingStepTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\InitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\FeatureNode), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\StepNode), false)
      #15 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Tester/Runtime/RuntimeScenarioTester.php(76): Behat\Behat\Tester\StepContainerTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\InitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\FeatureNode), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\ScenarioNode), false)
      #16 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Hook/Tester/HookableScenarioTester.php(74): Behat\Behat\Tester\Runtime\RuntimeScenarioTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\InitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\FeatureNode), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\ScenarioNode), false)
      #17 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/EventDispatcher/Tester/EventDispatchingScenarioTester.php(103): Behat\Behat\Hook\Tester\HookableScenarioTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\InitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\FeatureNode), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\ScenarioNode), false)
      #18 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Tester/Runtime/RuntimeFeatureTester.php(83): Behat\Behat\EventDispatcher\Tester\EventDispatchingScenarioTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\InitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\FeatureNode), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\ScenarioNode), false)
      #19 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Hook/Tester/HookableFeatureTester.php(72): Behat\Behat\Tester\Runtime\RuntimeFeatureTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\UninitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\FeatureNode), false)
      #20 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/EventDispatcher/Tester/EventDispatchingFeatureTester.php(71): Behat\Behat\Hook\Tester\HookableFeatureTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\UninitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\FeatureNode), false)
      #21 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Tester/Runtime/RuntimeSuiteTester.php(63): Behat\Behat\EventDispatcher\Tester\EventDispatchingFeatureTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\UninitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\FeatureNode), false)
      #22 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Hook/Tester/HookableSuiteTester.php(73): Behat\Testwork\Tester\Runtime\RuntimeSuiteTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\UninitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Testwork\Specification\GroupedSpecificationIterator), false)
      #23 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/EventDispatcher/Tester/EventDispatchingSuiteTester.php(72): Behat\Testwork\Hook\Tester\HookableSuiteTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\UninitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Testwork\Specification\GroupedSpecificationIterator), false)
      #24 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Tester/Runtime/RuntimeExercise.php(71): Behat\Testwork\EventDispatcher\Tester\EventDispatchingSuiteTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\UninitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Testwork\Specification\GroupedSpecificationIterator), false)
      #25 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/EventDispatcher/Tester/EventDispatchingExercise.php(70): Behat\Testwork\Tester\Runtime\RuntimeExercise->test(Array, false)
      #26 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Ordering/OrderedExercise.php(80): Behat\Testwork\EventDispatcher\Tester\EventDispatchingExercise->test(Array, false)
      #27 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Tester/Cli/ExerciseController.php(146): Behat\Testwork\Ordering\OrderedExercise->test(Array, false)
      #28 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Tester/Cli/ExerciseController.php(108): Behat\Testwork\Tester\Cli\ExerciseController->testSpecifications(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Array)
      #29 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Cli/Command.php(63): Behat\Testwork\Tester\Cli\ExerciseController->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      #30 vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php(262): Behat\Testwork\Cli\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      #31 vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(888): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      #32 vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(224): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Behat\Testwork\Cli\Command), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      #33 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Cli/Application.php(121): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      #34 vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(125): Behat\Testwork\Cli\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      #35 vendor/behat/behat/bin/behat(32): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
      #36 {main}
    When I press 'einloggen'  # FeatureContext::iPress()
    Then I should see 'Login' # FeatureContext::iShouldSee()

--- Failed scenarios:

    features/login.feature:7

1 scenario (1 failed)
3 steps (1 failed, 2 skipped)
0m0.10s (10.17Mb)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've been using Behat with Firefox for quite long time and we constantly had issues like you described. Sometimes we even downgraded Firefox version to be able to run Behat features.

We switched to [chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) and since then we never had any issues (if you on Mac, install it with `brew install chromedriver`). 
Here is our configuration for Behat:

```
default:
  gherkin:
    filters:
      tags: @mytag
  autoload:
    '': %paths.base%/bootstrap
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      base_url: https://site.local
      goutte:
        guzzle_parameters:
          verify: false
      browser_name: 'chrome'
      selenium2:
        capabilities: { "browserName": "chrome", "browser": "chrome", 'chrome': {'switches':['--no-sandbox']}}

  suites:
    mysuite:
      paths:    [ %paths.base%/features ]
      contexts:
        - FeatureContext
        - GuiContext
```

If you still want to use Firefox to be able to run Behat with Selenium, make sure you have the latest version of Selenium Standalone Server http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/.

Also, consider using Docker images with Selenium and browser installed on it https://hub.docker.com/u/selenium/, it is preconfigured and tested to be working.

**UPDATE 1**

Use your GuiContext without constructor and extend RawMinkContext:

```
class GuiContext extends RawMinkContext
{
    /**
     * @When /^wait (\d+) seconds?$/
     */
    public function waitSeconds($seconds)
    {
        $this->getSession()->wait(1000*$seconds);
    }
}
```

Once you specify `@javascript` tag in your feature, Behat will automatically switch to selenium driver.

**UPDATE 2:**

To start selenium execute the command:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.6.0.jar >& /tmp/selenium.log &
```

Assuming 3.6.0 is the latest version of selenium downloaded from [link](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
You can also require selenium server using composer:

```
composer require se/selenium-server-standalone
```

And then start it:

```
/your-project/vendor/bin/selenium-server-standalone
```

Comment: Hi, THANKS for your feedback and answer! I do everything you told me but I get still the same error msg. Maybe my FeatureContext.php isn't correct configured? Can you post your configuration?

Comment: @Emmanuel I just updated the config and added some recommendations, see if this help.

Comment: I am so thankfull about your help! Know behat detected the right local host but I still get the error msg that my connection could not opens because of no configuration. In my error msg is know `"System info: host: 'Emmanuel-macOS.local', ip: '` **172.20.71.92** `',...` I put that IP in my `wd_host` in my `behat.yml`. Do you have any idea what else could I do?

Comment: @Emmanuel how do you start your selenium server? Try to run this command  `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.6.0.jar >& /tmp/selenium.log &` and then `tail -f /tmp/selenium.log`, you might get some insights from the log.

Comment: @Emmanuel just realized that we are using selenium hub. If you start you selenium like `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.6.0.jar`, you don't have to specify `wd_host` in behat.yml. I'll update my post.

Comment: I start my selenium like in your last answere. you are able to see the resault of your other post [here](https://prnt.sc/h2b5mc) are you able to explain me how I am able to do it right?

Comment: @Emmanuel now try to remove `wd_host` from behat.yml and run again.

Comment: I get the same error. I think I am not able to create a session so my chrome will not start... do have an idea? I want to write some .features and test it but my chrome or firefox will not start and go to my website/webapplication ...

Comment: Can you post the full error please? Are there anything in selenium.log ?

Comment: Where i can find the selenium.log?

Comment: @Emmanuel I meant /tmp/selenium.log. `tail -f /tmp/selenium.log` after you start selenium.

Comment: Your selenium version  2.31 is a bit old, the newest one is 3.6 download it from http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/, where it says "Selenium Standalone Server".

Comment: I downloaded the standalone server 3.6.0 from the website again but in the log is still 2.31.

Comment: @Emmanuel If you run your behat command with `-vvv` flag it will give you more output. Please post the behat command you are trying to run and the full error you are getting from the command.

Comment: I have updated my post. Do you want continue this discussion in the chat?

Comment: @Emmanuel Yes we can discuss in the chat. In mean while try this skeleton I just setup https://github.com/zstate/behat-selenium-skeleton, see if you get the same error.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your upload. I did how you wrote but I get an other error now: `[Behat\Behat\Context\Exception\ContextNotFoundException]                         
  'MyProject\Context\FeatureContext' context class not found and can not be used.`

Comment: @Emmanuel `composer install` should do the trick. `behat` uses vendor autoloader and the namespace is defined in the composer.json.

Comment: @Emmanuel not  sure why you have this error, we probably have some differences in the environment. I tested this repo.

Comment: hey, no problem. I am thankful that you tried to help me :) thanks a lot.